# Thread 1: signal SIGABRT mutating method sent to immutable object'

Tags: swift3, ios10

i am new to Swift programming and have been working on a To-Do List app . I am trying to use the Permanent Data Storage to save the information entered by user,but i keep getting the error `"Thread 1: signal SIGABRT` " . When i checked the output log, i see the error

> "Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray
>   insertObject:atIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'"

My code is below. I use a simple textbox and a button:

```
@IBOutlet var text1: UITextField!

@IBAction func button1(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    let listObject = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "lists")

    var items:NSMutableArray

   if let tempitems = listObject as? NSMutableArray {

        items = tempitems

      items.addObjects(from: [text1.text!])

  } else {

        items = [text1.text!]

    }

    UserDefaults.standard.set(items, forKey: "lists")

    text1.text = ""

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The crash is exactly what it means: you can't mutate an immutable object. Try this:

```
var items: NSMutableArray!

if let listObject = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "lists") as? NSArray {
    items = listObject.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray
} else {
    items = NSMutableArray()
}

items.addObjects(from: [text1.text!])
```

Comment: Hello.. Thank you.. That worked. But what i dont understand is which part in the code is an immutable object. Because i have specified it as NSMutableArray and i thought it assigns and can be changed later.

Comment: **Declaring** the variable as mutable but then **assign** it to an immutable array make it immutable. It's probably a bug that your `if let ...` line succeeds